# Why "Memory corruption" at boot time when enabling AMD proprietary drivers?

Tags: graphic-drivers

First of all thank you to all of people participating to elementary Os development.

In order to stop switching to Windows partition to play advanced 3D games I am trying to enable the graphic card proprietary drivers on the elementary OS Freya of my HP Pavilion dv7 laptop.

Here are the hardware full spec :
http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-dv7-4100-Entertainment-Notebook-PC-series/4247665/document/c02643026/
There is two graphic card in this model, an Intel and a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650.

Whatever AMD drivers I tried (the one proposed by elementary OS Additional Drivers, compiled from AMD drivers sources, from ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates (stable) orppa:xorg-edgers/ppa (beta)) , everything seems fine during the installation but it always crash after a reboot during the elementary OS splash screen with the following error :

```
[ 63.350772] Corrupted low memory at ffff880000006598 (6598 phys) = 3c0000000000
[ 63.350864] Memory corruption detected in low memory
```

This happen even after a fresh install of elementary OS.

To successfully boot after that I need to enter in recovery mode and type "apt-get purge fglrx*".

Who succeed to install AMD proprietary driver with same king of hardware and moreover "how"?

Comment: Could you please fix the link to the hardware specs? Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Found something interesting for you: Does this thread help you? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=175365

Comment: Thanks for your answer BigBang. I fixed the hardware URL and will investigate your suggested post.  Option "Use the proprietary driver with powerxpress (a.k.a. pxp) support maintained by Vi0l0 (remember to check for xorg compatibility)." seems promising.

Comment: Could you report your findings? You can answer yourself and post the solution...